# What is the Catholic Church's teaching on paying respect to one's in-laws?

Tags: catholicism, commandments

The fourth commandment says that one should respect one's parents. I wish to know if the Catholic Church has made some rules which would govern one's conduct towards one's father-in-law and mother-in-law.

Comment: In-laws are not out-laws so I gather one should respect them as such!

Comment: And the two become one flesh so each is obligated to respect the parents of the other

Comment: Right, Ken Graham, becuse you are, by your own admision,  "Husband of the greatest woman I have ever known`'  !

Answer (score 1):

**What is the catholic Church's teaching on paying respect to one's in-laws?**

Did not Our Lord say:

> “A new command I give you: Love one another. As I have loved you, so you must love one another. By this everyone will know that you are my disciples, if you love one another”. [(John 13:34)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+13%3A34&version=ESV)

In-laws are simply our extended immediate extended family through marriage.

Our Lord also said:

> Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’[a] 31 The second is this: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’[b] There is no commandment greater than these.” [(Mark 12: 30-31)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark+12%3A30-31&version=NIV)

Do not forget that we must love and respect all people, strangers, in-laws as well as those we do not get along with. The [Golden Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Rule) applies to all people including our in-laws.

> "Do unto others as you would have them do unto you". [(Matthew 7:12)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_7:12)

The Fourth Commandment says that one should respect one's parents. In-laws are family by extension of marriage and they deserve our love and respect. It behooves us as Catholics to follow Our Lord’s words to the best of our ability.